# Force unsupported browsers to ignore VIBRATION API methods

Tags: javascript, vibration

I am using Vibration API to vibrate user device to improve UX.

```
navigator.vibrate(200);
```

The problem is it breaks my website on unsupported browsers/devices. I know I can check for vibration support before calling the vibrate method like this:

```
if("vibrate"  in navigator)  {
    // vibration API supported
}
```

But I have already published my website, its live. I require some kind of a hack which will force unsupported browsers/devices to ignore `navigator.vibrate()` method where ever used.

Comment: You can republish your website.

Comment: I know it can be solved by checking support before calling the function, just curious whether something like this exists or not.

Comment: You could just place a fake vibrate method on the navigator object.  eg.  `navigator.vibrate = function () {}`

Comment: Do you "require" such a hack or are you just "curious"? If you *can* republish your website, do so. It's the natural thing to do. The web is dynamic and changing by nature and there is no shame in republishing your website with changes to your code. I literally just uploaded a fix to one of my scripts 10 minutes before I saw your question. You can do the same.

Comment: @Keith you are the guy! Thanks a ton. You can post it as answer if you want.

Comment: @BoltClock I have extensively used `navigator.vibrate` in my project in multiple files and I don't have a cool IDE to do the refractor thing. I will definitely republish it with all necessary changes. Just didn't want it to be broken till I fix this.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

**METHOD 1**

```js
if(window.navigator && typeof window.navigator.vibrate !=='undefined')
{
    //Execute your code
    console.log("Vibrate API is supported by browser",window.navigator.vibrate);
}
else
{
    console.log("Browser issues: Vibrate API not supported");
}
```

**MEHTOD 2**

```js
try
{
    console.log("Vibrate API is supported by browser",window.navigator.vibrate);
    //Execute your code
}
catch(Err)
{
    console.log("Browser issues:",Err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870228/keith)

These 4 lines (kept in global scope) will stop unsupported browsers/devices from breaking your site.

```
let mainNavigator = window.navigator;
let navigator = {};
let vibrationSupport = "vibrate" in mainNavigator;
vibrationSupport ? navigator.vibrate = function(value) { mainNavigator.vibrate(value); } : navigator.vibrate = function(value) {};
```